# Solr keyword search as input

Tags: solr

I have only one field in my solr with following data

John Appleseed

John Doe

Clara Smith

John Smith

I want to give John & Smith as parameters to my solr query and get the following results -

John (3)

Smith (2)

Something like creating tags, passed as input parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with facet.query,  say solr returned 3 documents for query `q=ipod`.

if you use `q=ipod&facet=true&facet.query=ipod` in the request URL you get results as below. indicates 3 documents which has ipod in it.

```
 "facet_counts":{
    "facet_queries":{
      "ipod":3},
```

If you want doc count for multiple words in query give multiple `facet.query`

something like this `q=ipod belkin&facet=true&facet.query=ipod&facet.query=belkin` then you can expect results like below

```
"facet_counts":{
    "facet_queries":{
      "ipod":3,
      "belkin":2},
```

indicates 3 documents with word `ipod` and 2 documents with word `belkin`

Comment: if you use `facet.field` you can get all token and corresponding doc count for each token of matched documents. example: `facet.field=name`